# Authentication to SharePoint Online from InTune MDM Xamarin.Android device

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-msal, intune

I am working on Xamarin.Android app that needs to download documents from SharePoint Online (SPO) in the background thread (using SPO REST API right now). Users should be using an app, while it is quietly retrieving documents from SPO.
I have no experience working with Intune MDM or MSAL library for authentication. Android device is corporate-owned (COD) and enrolled in MS InTune. Is there a way to pick enrolled on-device user details and pass them with requests to SPO?
Options that I am investigating are:

- Integrate InTune SDK into app
- Use MSAL library with the app registration in Azure portal for authentication

I am trying to avoid using WebView/browser for SSO if possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are no experts here in this field, so after a lot of research and trials I worked out the solution. InTune SDK integration is not required if an Android mobile device is enrolled through InTune MDM, because Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL.NET) can use Intune Company Portal app (or Microsoft Authenticator) as a broker. Your Xamarn.Android app needs to be registered in Azure portal following these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app and adopting steps in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-android-single-sign-on tutorial to Xamarin.Android makes authentication work.
One point to note is that you need to specify and give admin consent for Graph and Sharepoint permissions to read User, Sites and Files.